# Why is my constructor unable to be found in the context of an object expression?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Code-example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(){ a = 5; }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    std::cout << a->A;//A is injected-class-name
}
```

Why does injected-class-name will be found instead of constructor? Moreover, we cannot invoke a constructor even if we write the following:

```
#include<iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(){ a = 5; }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    std::cout << a->A::A//A::A denote injected-class-name
}
```

Although, the 3.4.3.1/1 said:

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the
>   nested-name-specifier nominates a class C: — if the name specified
>   after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the
>   injected-class-name of C (Clause 9), or [...] the name is instead
>   considered to name the constructor of class C.

In an object-expression during the name lookup, followed after `->`, functions are not ignored.

So why does constructor cannot be found in that cases?

Comment: We return the the never-ending saga of C++ Arcana...

Comment: @KerrekSB, Perhaps DmitryFucintv is writing a C++ compiler.

Comment: The standard is pretty clear that "Constructors do not have names" [12.1/1]. I think it would probably be better if you took week or six off and just read the entire standard systematically, given that you're so interested in all its minutiae, rather than posting each section as a question one by one.

Comment: @dmitry-fucintv OT: As you already disclosed you're going to implement your own C++ parser/compiler, may you give a reason why you're actually doing this? Is it just to improve your skills for compiler building in general, or are you reinventing the wheel? There are already numerous c/c++ parsing frontends available, that fit almost all of the current standards definitions pretty well (in particular I have the LLVM clang frontend in mind). You can also make reuse of these frontends (and the AST of the parsed code) to provide any extension/application you'd want to have at the backend side.

Comment: @KerrekSB That ctors don't have namesdoesn't matter here, or does it?. Upvoted for the second part though.

Comment: @Arcoth: Since the constructor has no name, it cannot be found, because you cannot say its name. I think that's pertinent, because it shows that the OP's entire expectation of being able to "find" the constructor is doomed.

Comment: @KerrekSB If you don't want to answer my questions, so it is your decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really say it better than the standard:

> ---
>
> **12.1 Constructors** [class.ctor]
>
> Constructors do not have names. A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor.

`A` is not the name of a function, in your code.

Answer (score 1):

> So why does constructor cannot be found in that cases?

Read what you quote:

> if the name specified after the ***nested-name-specifier*** [...].

A *nested-name-specifier* contains a `::` (scope resolution operator) at the end. Do you see a `::` in `a->A`?